# Storing object in Google App Engine using JDO

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf, jdo, datastore

I'm using Google App Engine but I'm having some problem when I try to store objects in the datastore.
I'm using Eclipse Indico platform, JDO to describe the objects that I want to store and JSF technology for the user interface.
When I run my application on the ecliplse platform sometimes it works fine (objects are stored correctly) and sometimes it does't work and when the code is execude nothing happens (neither an error message), and if I delete the file war/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin before the execution it isn't recreated.
When I run the same application on Google App Engine the problem is the same: during the execution nothing happens or sometimes the last object stored is replaced by the last.
I don't understand why the same application, without any change works and doesn't work without a reason.

This is one of my object (getter and setter methods are omitted):

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class User implements Serializable {
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long idUser; 
@Persistent
private String email;
@Persistent
private String name;
@Persistent
private String surname;
@Persistent
private String password;
```

and this is the code that I use to store object:

```
public Utente creaUtente(User user) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

    try {
        user = pm.makePersistent(user);
    } catch (Exception e) {        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println(e.getMessage() + "DB-creaUtente");
    }
    finally{
        pm.close();
    }
    return user;        
  }
```

Any ideas to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues, first is you're using a try block with a generic catch so all errors go unreported due to second that you can't use `System.out.println` in App Engine.  You need to use the app engine [logging service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#Logging) to see the error.  Or if the application is still in development you can eliminate all your generic try blocks so you get a real stack trace.

As to why it isn't working 100% there isn't enough code there for me to diagnose it.

Comment: You still can use System.out.println in AppEngine though not recommended. out.println will write to INFO level, and error.println will write to WARNING level.

Comment: Also in this case nothing happens. I tried to execute the application in debug mode on the eclipse platform and the execution is interrupted because there is a "Source not found". In particular the problem is the class NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[]) line: not available. Eclipse instead of showing this class normally, shows: "Source not found." and a button "Edit Source Lookup Path...". There are no errors in console even in debug mode. Is this class the cause of the problem?

Comment: The log for DataNucleus (DEBUG level) would tell you exactly what the makePersistent call does. There are ample docs on using JDK1.4 logging to identify where it is being created.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you an answer as why the later creation of user override the previously created based on your provided code, but I suspect it has something to do with the argument USER you passed in.

Can you please check the if you have set the primary key of the User entity (idUser) to the creaUtente() function?

Since the User class's primary key is auto generated, you should leave it as empty and system will generate the id for you. If you provide a id, then the second write will override the existing one because they are sharing the same id.

Comment: I don't set the userId in the creaUtente() function. In my JSF java bean I create an User object and then I set its parameters (all except the id), and then I call the creaUtente(user) method.